# How can I sort Xfce's whisker menu list alphabetically?

Tags: xfce, menu, xfce-panel, whisker

I have [xfce4-panel 4.12](http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-panel/start) and as you see in screenshot, the Whisker menu is not sorted. I didn't find any option for sorting the menu so the question is how can I sort it alphabetically ?

[image]

I can only sort Favorites by right-clicking on any of them in the whisker menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click on start button and select Properties. Then uncheck both "show generic application names" and "Show menu hierarchy".

[image]

Comment: This answer is partially correct. User will also need to *uncheck* the option `Show menu hierarchy` for the applications to be sorted by name. I have confirmed this, using Whisker Menu 1.3.2-1 in Xubuntu 14.04.

Comment: yes you are right, I update the answer.

Comment: This menu has since changed. I'm unsure if this solution still works.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the easiest way to do this is by using an application called MenuLibre. It is usually installed by default (under settings) but can be installed with `sudo apt-get install menulibre` if not.

BTW, the application appears in the menu as "Menu Editor".

Comment: Tnx for answer. I installed the program. Where is the sort option in this program? My list appears sorted in program, but it is still not sorted in main menu.

Comment: Also when I run `menulibre`, I receive this warning: `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/menulibre/MenuEditor.py:28: PyGIWarning: GMenu was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('GMenu', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import GdkPixbuf, Gio, GLib, GMenu, Gtk`

Comment: I don't believe you can automatically sort with this program but you can order them however you like manually.  The system I have also shows that error but it still appears to function correctly. Not sure why MenuLibre is showing your menu differently to how it actually is.

Answer (score 0):

Xfce edit menu now has sort button (smaller arrow with three small dots) next to the up/down move arrows at bottom left corner of the app. (Xfce version 4.14)
To get there right click on the applications button,choose properties,the Applications Menu window appears. Click on the Edit Menu button.
Sort by highlighting one item of a category, and pressing the arrow with the three dots  [libre Menu clip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58gvk.png)

Comment: can you add a screenshot? tnx