# Really strange problem with python

Tags: 17.10, python3, alacarte, menulibre, caffeine

Firstly I have problem with caffeine:
[Caffeine doesn't work on Ubuntu 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1006905/caffeine-doesnt-work-on-ubuntu-17-10)

I didn't bind it with python. BTW, running ubuntu under Xorg didn't help.

Secondly, I received strange error when was trying to test python program. I ran

```
 python3 programname.py test
```

and receive

```
File "sampletest.py", line 1, in <module>
    import unittest
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/unittest/__init__.py", line 59, in <module>
    from .case import (TestCase, FunctionTestCase, SkipTest, skip, skipIf,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/unittest/case.py", line 6, in <module>
    import logging
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from string import Template
ImportError: cannot import name 'Template'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 21, in <module>
    from urllib.request import urlopen
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 88, in <module>
    import http.client
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 71, in <module>
    import email.parser
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/email/parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from email.feedparser import FeedParser, BytesFeedParser
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/email/feedparser.py", line 27, in <module>
    from email._policybase import compat32
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/email/_policybase.py", line 7, in <module>
    from email import header
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/email/header.py", line 16, in <module>
    import email.quoprimime
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/email/quoprimime.py", line 44, in <module>
    from string import ascii_letters, digits, hexdigits
ImportError: cannot import name 'ascii_letters'
```

Then I received error after running alacarte: [How can I sort Xfce's whisker menu list alphabetically?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/779469/how-can-i-sort-xfces-awhisker-menu-list-alphabetically)

BTW, I receive the similar error when run menulibre:

```
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/menulibre/MenuEditor.py:28: PyGIWarning: GMenu was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('GMenu', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import GdkPixbuf, Gio, GLib, GMenu, Gtk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/menulibre/MenulibreApplication.py", line 1717, in do_activate
    self.win = MenulibreWindow(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/menulibre/MenulibreApplication.py", line 207, in __init__
    self.configure_application_treeview(builder)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/menulibre/MenulibreApplication.py", line 462, in configure_application_treeview
    self.treeview = MenulibreTreeview.Treeview(self, builder)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/menulibre/MenulibreTreeview.py", line 43, in __init__
    self._configure_treeview(builder)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/menulibre/MenulibreTreeview.py", line 54, in _configure_treeview
    treestore = MenuEditor.get_treestore()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/menulibre/MenuEditor.py", line 113, in get_treestore
    menu = get_menus()[0]
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/menulibre/MenuEditor.py", line 175, in get_menus
    menu = MenuEditor()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/menulibre/MenuEditor.py", line 227, in __init__
    self.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/menulibre/MenuEditor.py", line 245, in load
    if not self.tree.load_sync():
GLib.Error: g-markup-error-quark: Error on line 1 char 1: Document was empty or contained only whitespace (1)
```

I'm sure problem in my python interpreter, but I don't know what it can be. Please, help

P.S. I'm new in linux. So, please, explain as simple as possible

P.P.S. I have Ubuntu 17.10

Answer (score 0):

For `menulibre` part you should reinstall it with its dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gir1.2-gmenu-3.0 gnome-menus libgnome-menu-3-0 menulibre
```

Then launch it with `menulibre` command or from Menu.

Comment: I have the same problem after that command